# I wanted to know how we could add text to the days that are shown on a Jcalendar?

Tags: java, eclipse, jcalendar

So I'm using the Jcalendar in eclipse, and I wanted to know if there was a way I could show text that the user enters on the day that the user selects using Jdatechooser on the Jcalendar. I also wanted to change the colour of that particular day that the user has entered on my Jcalendar.

I haven't found anything on the internet yet that would help me show text on the Jcalendar days that are displayed. I haven't really written any code for it since right now I have no idea how I go about doing it
I would want my calendar to look something like this image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzKwR.png)

Comment: [This JCalendar?](https://toedter.com/jcalendar/)  I don't think so.

Comment: No, this isn't Jcalendar, this is what I want Jcalendar to look like.

Comment: It doesn't look to me like like JCalendar is capable of doing what you want.

Comment: Then What can I use in java to accomplish this?

Comment: Something other than JCalendar.  You'll have to do some market research and find a control that is more suited to your needs.

Comment: `JCalendar` is a date _chooser_, not a day _planner_; you probably want  an appointment book.

Comment: Is there a Jar file for this appointment book or do I have to build the entire thing by hand